# Accelerate remote file share

Tags: cloudflare, webdav

I have a Windows file server (Windows 2016) that is hosted in PH that I want to share in TW.

An immediate option I opted for is the use of webdav. However, its performance is subpar when being accessed in TW.

I use cloudflare to reverse proxy my origin IP and enable HTTPs access.

Is there a way I could accelerate the access of the file server in TW? If cost is needed, it can be an option except if it is an MPLS connection (which I cannot afford).

Is there a way to dedup the traffic to reduce overhead?

Comment: `I have a Windows file server (Windows 2016) that is hosted in PH that I want to share in TW.` - What? Are we supposed to know what PH and TW mean?

Comment: Do PH and TW stand for Philippines and Taiwan?

Comment: Yes it does. Sorry to abbreviate it

Answer (score 1):

It really looks like you should setup and configure [BranchCache](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/branchcache/branchcache).  Microsoft specifically built this technology to solve the problem you're describing.  Just be cautious when multiple users are modifying the same files, as you can end up with race-conditions where user A in TW makes a change, and user B in PH makes a change... and then both click save at (near) the same time.  You might end up with a screwed up document.  (Keep in mind, that this feature requires "Enterprise" versions of Windows clients (i.e. Windows 10 Enterprise))

Comment: This looks promising. Regarding shared resource, we are aiming to segregate which shares PH can read/write/modify that TW only needs to have read-only (and vice versa) to avoid saving conflicts. My client PCs are running Windows 10 in a VDI. I am however would wan to confirm if BrancCache (say in distributed mode) will work across different Active Directory forest?

Comment: Another question I am confused is that if my clients are running Pro Edition, what does it mean when it says BITS support only?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, As long as the share is available to the end user, it will be able to be cached.  Any clients in the forrest would be able to cache the shares, and share the content to any peers.
Unfortunately, BITS won't work for what you are trying to do.  Enterprise adds SMB support for branchcache, which is what I am talking about.

Comment: I am corrected. My TW PCs are on a persistent VDI running Windows 10 Enterprise Edition